# SCSS - Simple Each Array

Tags: arrays, sass

i think everyone will understand, what i try to to:

```
  @each $num, $mult, $space in ('01', 1, '16px'), ('02', 2, '32px'), ('03', 3, '48px'), ('04', 4, '64px'), ('05', 5, '80px'), ('06', 6, '96px') {
    &.item-#{$num} {
      right: $sideNavWidth * $mult + $space;
    }
  }
```

but the end result for item-01 is: right: "320px16px"; This is ofc invalid... Why Node-Sass dont give me a clean result? What is wrong with my array?

Its Same like:

```
  &.item-01 {
    right: $sideNavWidth + 16px;
  }
  &.item-02 {
    right: $sideNavWidth * 2 + 32px;
  }
  &.item-03 {
    right: $sideNavWidth * 3 + 48px;
  }
  &.item-04 {
    right: $sideNavWidth * 4 + 64px;
  }
  &.item-05 {
    right: $sideNavWidth * 5 + 80px;
  }
  &.item-06 {
    right: $sideNavWidth * 6 + 96px;
  }
```

And end Result must be:

```
.item-01{right:336px}
  .item-02{right:672px}
  .item-03{right:1008px}
  .item-04{right:1344px}
  .item-05{right:1680px}
  .item-06{right:2016px}
```

And anyone see a smarter way to do that, what i try to do?

Best regards.

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: I Updated my post

Comment: Do not change the code in the question. If there are any updates, append it after the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes from the pixel values in your array.

Like this:

```
$sideNavWidth: 320px;

.e {
  @each $num, $mult, $space in ('01', 1, 16px), ('02', 2, 32px), ('03', 3, 48px), ('04', 4, 64px), ('05', 5, 80px), ('06', 6, 96px) {
    &.item-#{$num} {
      right: $sideNavWidth * $mult + $space;
    }
  }
}
```

In the comments you asked for a more efficient way to do this, so I came up with this:

```
$sideNavWidth: 320px;

.n {
  @for $i from 1 through 6 {
    $z: '';
    @if ($i < 10) { $z: '0'; }
    &.item-#{$z}#{$i} {
      right: ($sideNavWidth * $i) + (($i * 2) * 8);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahh thanks thats it! =) And you think, that there is any way, to solve this "smarter"? (shorter code)

Comment: @Budi No problem! I updated my answer with a more efficient version of your code.

Comment: oh yeah! This looks awesome! i dont realy understand the code, but its very short and looks very clean. Thanks alot for this =)

Comment: Basically it's just more dynamic. For example, if you wanted to add more elements, you could change the 6 to a 10. Also, if you wanted to make your spacing smaller, you could change the 8 to like a 5 or something.

Comment: Damn.. i realy dont understand your code. its to complicated for me. can you please check again my first post? i need a special rule for the sidebar status "closed"

Comment: If you want the inverse, just use the existing code within a &:sidenav-closed, and override the right to 0. but this should be a new question since the new question doesn't reflect the accepted answer.